# RVM Install 1.8.7 in OSX

Tags: ruby-on-rails, macos, rvm, ruby-on-rails-2, ruby-1.8.7

I received a new Macbook Pro for work and started to setup my local machine for development. I installed RVM, then proceeded to install different ruby versions: 2.1, 2.0, 1.9, and 1.8.7. I need 1.8.7 because I will be working on an older site running this legacy version of ruby.

Anyway, when I type: `rvm install 1.8.7`, rvm installs both 1.8.7-p374 and 1.8.7-head. These installs were successful. When I type: `rvm use 1.8.7`, it defaults to the ruby-1.8.7-head version.

Why does rvm insist on installing both versions of ruby 1.8.7?

Comment: because of `rvm` internals, you have to specify full version to install the specific one

Comment: But when I type: `rvm install 2.0`, it installs only one version of ruby 2.0: ruby-2.0.0-p481

Comment: That is because there is the only version for 2.0.0

Answer (score 0):

Please specify explicit full version of ruby to install:

```
rvm install 1.8.7-p374
```

In case of version [ruby-2.0](/questions/tagged/ruby-2.0), you get the only version because there is the only one for the specified.